# what kind of 'For Loop' is this?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

hey guys i have this code from a video tutorial that confused me :

```
import maya.cmds as mc

def jointHierarchy(topJoint , lastJoint = True):

    jointsLists = mc.listRelatives(topJoint , type = 'joint' , ad = True)
    jointsLists .append (topJoint)
    jointsLists . reversed()

    wholeChane = jointsLists [:]
    if not lastJoint:
        jointsWithoutEnd = [ j for j in jointsLists if mc.listRelatives( j , type = 'joint' ,c =1 )]
```

what kind of loop is this

```
'''
    if not lastJoint:
        jointsWithoutEnd = [ j for j in jointsLists if mc.listRelatives( j , type = 'joint' ,c =1 )]
'''
```

do we have any structure like this

```
j for j in jointsLists if mc.listRelatives( j , type = 'joint' ,c =1 )
```

i tried this code and it worked correctly

any help

Comment: This is a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). Is that the question?

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is just like:**

```
jointsWithoutEnd=[]
for j in jointsLists:
    if mc.listRelatives(j,type='joint',c=1):
         jointsWithoutEnd.append(j)
```

**EDIT:** As RobertB said, that is list comprehension : https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions
*Hope that helps.*

Comment: Thx a lot . thats what i wante